# jQuery: save user's choice for having drop-down visible or closed on next visit

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, session-state

I have a drop-down on my site that I want visible to any first-time visitor, but if the user closes it, then I want to keep it closed on next visit for the same user.

Can I do this just with jQuery or do I need to pass the state back to the server (via Ajax?) and use server's session capabilities?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookies (to store the preference), or if you have authentication on your site, you could `POST` back via AJAX and update your users preferences (this will have the advantage of not relying on cookies expiring/being deleted).

Comment: Well, if the cookies have expired or being deleted, authentification would fail too, wouldn't it? I don't see any point of using ajax.

Comment: @Briedis But then you can login again, and the state of their preferences is still stored...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies, it can be achieved with plain javascript. This is a nice [resource](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for learning to deal with cookies.